# Capacity of cascade binary symmetric channels

Tags: digital-communications, statistics, channelcoding, random-process, communication-standard

Let's imagine that we have interconnected in cascade $L$ binary symmetric channels each with the same transition probability $p(y|x) \in \{p, q=1-p\}$, where the output of each BSC is connected to the input of the next.

The overall channel is also a BSC channel, but what happens as $L \to \infty$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [binary symmetric channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_symmetric_channel) (BSC) can be characterized by its complemented probability $p$. Its well-known capacity is

$$C = 1 - H(p) = 1 - (-p\log(p) - (1-p)\log(1-p))$$

where $H(p)$ is [binary entropy function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_entropy_function):

[image]

---

A $L-$concatenated BSC, which is also a BSC characterized by $p_L$, can be visualized as in the figure below

[image: L concatenated BSC]

The complemented probability $p_L$ is derived

\begin{align}
p_L &= p_{L-1} (1-p) + (1-p_{L-1}) p \\
&= p + (1-2p)p_{L-1}\\
\implies 1 - 2 p_L &= (1-2p)(1-2p_{L-1}) \\
\implies 1 - 2 p_L &= (1-2p)^L \\
\end{align}

Thus
$$p_L = \frac{1}{2}(1 - (1-2p)^L)$$

If $p=0$ then $p_L = 0$, $H(p_L) = 0$ and $C = 1$.

If $p=1$ then $p_L = 0$ or $p_L = 1$ depending on $L$ is pair or impair; $H(p_L) = 0$ and $C = 1$.

If $0 < p < 1$ then $\lim_{L \to \infty} p_L = 0.5$; $H(p_L) = 1$ and $C = 0$.

**Conclusion**: if the unit BSC is not certain $(p \neq 0, 1)$, the capacity of infinitely-concatenated BSC tends to $0$.

Comment: Wow @AlexTP . Incredible answer but how did you get from:
p_L =p+(1-2p)p_{L-1}
To:
p_L = \frac{1}{2}(1 - (1-2p)^L)
?
Thank you!!

Comment: @Cristo see my update

Comment: @Cristo you may be interested in Dilip Sarwate's approach, which is much natural, to prove the complemented probability of $L$-cascade BSC.

Comment: The link to [Prof Sarwate answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/44192/26081)

Answer (score 2):

A cascade of $L$ binary symmetric channels (BSCs) with cross-over probability $p$ is the same as a single BSC with cross-over probability 
$$p_L = \left.\left.\frac 12 \right(1 - (1-2p)^L\right).\tag{1}$$
To get to $(1)$, note that the cascaded BSC output is incorrect if and only if the transmitted bit was flipped an *odd* number of times as it traversed the cascade; even numbers of flips result in error-free transmission in accordance with the age-old principle that two wrongs make a right. The number of flips is a Binomial$(L,p)$ random variable $X$ for which
\begin{align}
P(X ~\text{odd}) &= \sum_{i=1,3,5,\ldots}\binom{L}{i}p^i (1-p)^{L-i}\\
&= ~~~\frac 12\left(\sum_{i=1,3,5,\ldots}\binom{L}{i}p^i (1-p)^{L-i} + \sum_{i=0,2,4,\ldots}\binom{L}{i}p^i (1-p)^{L-i}\right)\\
& ~~~~+ \frac 12\left(\sum_{i=1,3,5,\ldots}\binom{L}{i}p^i (1-p)^{L-i} - \sum_{i=0,2,4,\ldots}\binom{L}{i}p^i (1-p)^{L-i}\right)\\
&= \frac 12\left(\sum_{i=0}^L\binom{L}{i}p^i (1-p)^{L-i} - \sum_{i=0}^L \binom{L}{i}(-p)^i (1-p)^{L-i} \right)\\
&= \left.\left.\frac 12 \right(1 - (1-2p)^L\right).
\end{align}
As AlexTP points out, $p_L \to \frac 12$ for all $p \in (0,1)$, and so the non-trivial cascaded BSC has capacity approaching $0$ as $L \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit late, but the problem has quite an elegant solution based on the Fourier transform and I wanted to add it.

The action of the BSC can be modeled as a$\pmod 2$ sum of the data bit, $X$, and a random noise bit, $N$, who's probability distribution is $P(N=0)=1-p$ and $P(N=1)=p$,

$$Y = X \oplus N.$$

The distribution over the output, $Y$, is a [convolution of the quantities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions) $P(X)$ and $P(N)$,

$$P(Y=y) = \sum_{x \in \{0,1\}} P(X=x)P(N=x\oplus y).$$

This is a linear transformation of the probabilities. The circulant convolution matrix obtained from one of the vectors is diagonalized by the 2x2 DFT *Hadamard* matrix,

$$H = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix},$$

and the convolution becomes a product of spectra in the transform domain. The sum of $L$ identically distributed noise bits corresponds to exponentiation in the transform domain followed by an inverse transform,

$$H^{-1}\left(H\begin{bmatrix}1-p\\p\end{bmatrix}\right)^L = \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}{1 + (1 - 2p)^L}\\{1 - (1 - 2p)^L}\end{bmatrix},$$

where the second element of the result vector represents the probability $P(N_1 \oplus N_2 \oplus N_3 \oplus \ldots \oplus N_L = 1)$, which is the flip probability for the cascaded BSC.